# Python: Log pixel-intensity values from a video-file

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, data-science, video-processing

I read in a video as a grayscale. I mark a circular contour on each frame of the video and try to record the intensity of each pixel on this contour:

```
    frameCount += 1
    currentTimestamp = timestamp + frameCount/fps 
    file = open("myRecord.txt", "a+") #a+ to append to file
    file.write(str(currentTimestamp))
    circleSegment = get_circle_segment(center_pt, 60, 360) #this function returns a list of tuples, where each tuple (x,y) contains x- and y-coordinates of a point along the circular contour
    for el in circleSegment: 
        pixel = gray_frame[el[1],el[0]]
        #log information 
        file.write('\t' + str(pixel))
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()
```

This works perfectly for a circular arch of up to 180° and even beyond (I have tested with 181° as well). However, as soon as I go beyond a certain value, e.g. 270° or 359° or 360° (a complete circle, which is what I want), the data logged simply contains chinese characters.

I have no idea what may cause this issue! Can it be that as soon as my txt-file goes beyond 1,000 KB something goes wrong?

after comments, this code works:

```
 frameCount += 1
    currentTimestamp = timestamp + frameCount/fps 
    storeData = []
    storeData.append(currentTimestamp)
    circleSegment = get_circle_segment(center_pt, 60, 360) 
    for el in circleSegment: 
        pixel = gray_frame[el[1],el[0]]
        storeData.append(pixel)

    #log information 
    file = open("myRecord.txt", mode="a+") #a+ to append to file
    for element in storeData:
        file.write('\t' + str(element))
    file.write('\n')
    file.close ()
```

Comment: If your video is not too long, try storing all data in memory and dump it to file after the `for` loop. That way, you can choose to inspect what is logged.

Comment: thx Quang! ... I'm not sure what you mean with this, though. I am logging my data in a txt-file, so can I not inspect what is being logged? The txt-file is created when I run the code, and I can open it. It's just that it contains weird characters

Comment: And now you don't know if the chinese characters come from your code's bug or from the pixel value. If you store it in an array, you can review what it is before writing to disk. Plus, you program will perform better since it doesn't have to keep constant writing task.

Comment: You're right, Quang. I have edited my question, and the code given there now works! ...wow, this was really strange for me. Thank you so much!